# Commercial product using GANs

Tags: patent-infringement, machine-learning

I am thinking of creating a commercial product using GAN neural networks. How can I find out if the work done so far by others on which I will build upon is not patent protected. I would not want to invest a lot of time building something which will get shutdown due to legal issues.

Comment: I’m not sure what GAN is, but the answer is going to be: do a patent search.